# Show/hide a div on click, hide div on outside div click

Tags: jquery

I want to
`1. Show and hide a div when I click on the div.`
`2. Hide Div when click out side div.`
Here is my code
**HTML**

```
<div id="div_1">Click me</div>
<div id="div_2">Show hide text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div_2{
    display:none;
    border:1px solid black
}
#div_1{
    border:1px solid black;
    }
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#div_1').on('click', function () {
    $("#div_2").fadeToggle("fast");
});
$('html').on('mouseup', function (e) {
    $("#div_2").fadeOut("fast");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/59os3yeq/)
**Problem**
It is not working when i click on the div to show, outside div to hide then again on div to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the `mouseup` event from propagating from the clicked `div` element to the `html` element:

```
$('#div_1').on('click', function () {
    $("#div_2").fadeToggle("fast");
}).on('mouseup', function (e) {;
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$('html').on('mouseup', function () {
    $("#div_2").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/59os3yeq/1/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#div_1').on('click', function () {
    $("#div_2").stop().fadeToggle("fast");
});
$('html').on('mouseup', function () {
    $("#div_2").stop().fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Use `.stop()` to clear the animation queue, and prevent the fade running twice.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/59os3yeq/3/